# Exporting Key from HtmlUnit into wireshark for debugging

Tags: ssl, https, wireshark, htmlunit, tls1.2

The root problem I am trying to solve is to view the (encrypted) requests I am making from HtmlUnit(http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) inside of wireshark. I can see the packets and Under Secure Sockets Layer, I can see that TLSv1.2 is being utilized in wireshark, but I need to see the contents of the packet. I have read information on: [exporting firefox keys](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/) and on: [using those keys in wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) from a browser into wireshark for decryption is feasible, but HtmlUnit is not a 'traditional' browser. I know it is possible, I just do not know what info I need and where to get it. Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you need the SSL files of the server you are connecting too and not those of the "Browser" ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is simpler to enable HttpClient wire log.

```
      java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
```

This will dump all outgoing and incoming content to the log.

Comment: I will give this a shot. I typically use HttpClient OR HTMLUnit. It didn't really dawn on me that HTMLUnit is using HttpClient as well.

Comment: This alone doesn't seem to do anything. Is there some additional logging configuration that needs to be done for htmlUnit?

Comment: System properties did the trick :   System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire", "SEVERE");